# Variable keeps resetting to default value

Tags: java, variables

I am making a platforming game and when the player presses space it shoots a fireball and when the fireball is colliding with the enemy it takes the health down by one, which it does fine, but it then resets it back to the initial value and I can't figure out why

Enemy Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Enemy implements ActionListener{
private Image enemy;
private int velocity=0;
public int enemyhp=3;
private int x=500,y=380;
private boolean isAlive = true;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(isAlive){
    g.drawImage(enemy, x, y, null);
    }
}

public Enemy(){
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void update(){
    enemy = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\steven.greens10\\Desktop\\Programs\\Raw  Java\\Platform\\res\\enemy.png").getImage();

    if(enemyhp==0){
        die();
    }
    x+=velocity;


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    move();
    System.out.println(enemyhp);
}

private void move() {
    x-=5;
}

void addX(int speed){
    velocity=speed;
}

int getX(){
    return x;
}

int getY(){
    return y;
    }

int getWidth(){
    return 40;
}

int getHeight(){
    return 40;
}


public void takeDamage(){
enemyhp-=1;

}

public void die(){
    isAlive=false;
    x=100000;
    y=10000;
}

public void setX(){
    isAlive=true;
    x=500;
}
public void setY(){
    y=380;
}

}
```

The method that checks if the fireball and the enemy are colliding and if they are it calls the function in the enemy class that reduces the health.

```
public void update(){

   if(isCollidingWithEnemy){
       enemy.takeDamage();
       isVisible=false;
       x=10000; y=10000;
   }
```

When I run the code the enemy's health is outputted because of the timer and it says 3 until I shoot the enemy then it says "2 3 3 3 2"

Comment: The `enemyhp` variable is public; everyone can set a new value for this variable. I suspect somewhere else in your code you are forcing `enemyhp` to a value of `3` Mark it as private, and create getter/setter methods to access it. You will then be able to see where you are setting a value for this variable, and correct the situation.

Comment: Small thing I noticed,  but change this `if(enemyhp==0){` to `if(enemyhp <= 0){`.  I believe your `enemyhp` can go below 0.

Comment: @Laf's idea is as good as any. I don't see where your problems are in the code posted. It's always a good idea to hide as much data as possible from outside classes, to encapsulate your code. Also you'll want to use a debugger to see why your program is misbehaving.

Comment: You might also be running into threading issues.

Comment: Make sure you have only one `Enemy` and check how often you call `new Enemy()`.  You might accidentally replace your object with a new instance periodically.  One way to check is to give each object a unique name or ID and print that out along with the current `enemyhp`.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use the `Enemy` class?

Comment: @NathanielJones You were right, I made another Enemy object thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might accidentally replace your object with a new instance periodically. Make sure you have only one `Enemy` and check how often you call `new Enemy()`.

One way to check is to give each object a unique name or ID and print that out along with the current `enemyhp`.  For instance:

```
public class Enemy implements ActionListener {
    private static int nextID = 0;
    private final int id; /* final members must be set in the constructor and cannot be changed afterward */
    public int enemyhp=3;
    /* ... */

    public Enemy(){
        id = nextID++;
        /* ... */
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Enemy " + id + ": enemyhp=" + enemyhp;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        move();
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    /* ... */
}
```